# WP Query Wordpress Post Type with the same Taxonomy name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, slug

This is what I have:

- Custom Post type "Books" with Taxononies/Categories "Genre" and "Author"
- Another Custom Post Type "Authors" which have all author
  pictures and bios.

This is what I want to do:

- On the single "Book" page, have a sidebar with the books "Author"
  picture and bio.

I know how to get the "Author" Taxonomy of a "Book" post, but the information I need is from the "Author" Custom Post Type with the same name. The only thing i can think of is that the slug for both would be the same (i.e. if the books author was "John Smith", the taxonomy would be "john-smith" and the post that I need to query from my "Authors" Custom Post Type would also be "john-smith"). I just don't know how to go about getting it or if there is another way of doing it.

I think it should be something like this:

```
   $bookauthor = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'author', array("fields" => "slug"));
   $custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'authors',
   'name' => $bookauthor
```

or this:

```
   $bookauthor = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'author');
   $bookauthorslug = $bookauthor[0]->slug;
   $custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type' => 'author',
   'name' => $bookauthorslug
```

But neither works.

Comment: What part(s) do you not know how to get?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include your **current code**, and explain what's not working as expected, or is happening unexpectedly.

Comment: There is no code yet. I need to query the author custom post type that has the same name as the book's taxonomy. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: From what it sounds like you're trying to do, you might take a look at the Posts-to-Posts plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/), and skip the taxonomy completely.